# Using Dispatcher to change a label's foreground throws an exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-properties, dispatcher

I am trying to make a CPU friendly infinite loop which will update a label every 2 seconds.

When it comes to update the label, I can use `Dispatcher` to change its `Content` and `ToolTip` values, but I can't change its `Foreground` for some reason.

> **InvalidOperationException**:
>   can not use a DependencyObject that belongs to another thread than its Freezable parent.

There is my code:

```
private void SetPing(Brush foreground, string content, string tooltip)
{
    try
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)(() =>
        {
            this.Ping.Content = content;
            this.Ping.ToolTip = tooltip;
        }));

        // this.Dispatcher or this.Ping.Dispatcher throws the same error
        this.Ping.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            this.Ping.Foreground = foreground;
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this code from the `PerformPing` method here:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        this.PerformPing(this.Host);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}).Start();
```

(Yes, I know this is not a CPU-friendly loop, I made this for testing purposes).

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say for sure what the problem is. But based on the tiny bit of code you did share, I would guess that you are creating your `Brush` object in the background thread. That is not generally allowed. You might get it to work by calling `Freeze()` on the `Brush` after you create it. But frankly, it would be better if you learned the correct way to write a WPF program, including using MVVM/data binding with styles. Then you wouldn't need `BeginInvoke()` at all. (And, using `Thread.Sleep(1)` is _not_ _"CPU-friendly"_.)

Comment: The entire code does not add that much. The only thing that `PerformPing` does is to perform a ping and call `SetPing` with the result, where the `Brush` object is retrieved via a `BrushConverter`. Is that helping? I'll try `Freeze()`. 

Additionnaly, this is a very little program I made for my own. I don't need styles nor data binding in this one.

Moreover, like I said `(Yes, I know this is not a CPU-friendly loop, I made this for testing purposes).` 

But thank you anyway.

Comment: _"I don't need styles nor data binding in this one"_ -- sure you do. Just because it's _"a very little program [you] made for [your] own"_, that doesn't mean there's no value in doing it _right_.

Comment: You are right. But there are better ways to say it. I mean, *tact*. But whatever, you helped me, thank you. I answer this thread with an acceptable response, even if there is a better way to achieve this without using `Dispatcher`, as you *pointed it out*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho)'s answer, I figured out that the brush object was created in the background thread, and that is was the thing that caused the issue. Creating the brush in the `Dispatcher` call solves the issue.

```
private void SetPing(long ping, string content, string tooltip)
{
    try
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)(() =>
        {
            this.Ping.Content = content;
            this.Ping.ToolTip = tooltip;
            this.SetDock();
        }));

        if (this.EnableColors)
        {
            this.Ping.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)(() =>
            {
                this.Ping.Foreground = this.GetColorByPing(ping);
            }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Where `GetColorByPing()` returns something like `return (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#b71c1c");`